# How can my neural network model find which list (from my dataset) is closest to the input list from user in terms of the data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

My dataset is a list containing a lot of lists.
From the user I am going to take another list as an input.
How can I approach this problem through Neural Network?
How can I get my neural network model to tell me which list(from my dataset) is closest to the list taken from the user in terms of data..

Input from user - a list.
.
Output (prediction) - index of the list in my dataset that is the closest to the input list
.
I have 50 lists in my dataset as a single list.
I have gone with an ANN model and my code is this _

```
ann=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50,activation='softmax'))
ann.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
ann.fit(x,y,batch_size=32,epochs=50)
.
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If you want to find the "closest" (whatever that means) from your dataset, you don't need a neural network. Just go through the dataset and find and compare each entry to the user's input. NNs are for generalizing the data, so you can predict the output for new entries considering all your dataset entries.

Comment: The reason we are going for a NN is that maybe the input from user may not match any of the list in our dataset. But still we need to get the "closest identical" (if that makes sense). In that case won't we need to generalize the data ?

Comment: Hi Pramit, I'm having a hard time understanding what it is exactly that you want to do from your description. Is it something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning ? In any case, having only fifty data points might be a problem for training a neural network. ANNs typically require much more data.

Comment: Look up siamese neural networks or L2 normalized embeddings with triplet loss